# Syntax Highlighting in Groovy-Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I recently decided to make the jump from Java to Groovy (I'm a fairly new programmer), and so I downloaded the plugin for it for Eclipse. However, upon starting it up I realized that several things highlighted in Java, namely fields, types, etc., remain the generic white. While this isn't a massive issue, I would like to better tell things at a glance (and have a more aesthetically pleasing work environment). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: http://mydigitalbricks.blogspot.com/2011/12/changing-syntax-highlighting-for.html